# 'Like' button on my blog

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

It should be very easy to make a [like button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like_button) on my blog work, and I think I have set it up correctly, but I still get this error:

> The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe:
> Body of an error/warning message. Title is: Sorry, this post contains a blocked URL
> For more information, visit the [Help Center](http://www.facebook.com/help/). If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please [let us know](/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal).
>
> Have run debugger tool and result:
> http://kirtev.net63.net/ is blocked or is being accessed too frequently, so we're not fetching it.

It looks like it has got blacklisted. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody, I have found out that the problem is with my free hosting namespace that is filtered by Facebook ...

Trying a share, I got this message from Facebook:

> Sorry, this post contains a blocked URL
>   The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe: net63.net
>   For more information, visit the Help Center. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

So the only option is migrating website to a new domain or forget about it...

I hope this will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually quite a few wordpress Facebook Like Plugins available; eg. this one:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-button/

Answer (score 0):

It may be your free hosting that have been blacklisted.
Free hostings are often used to test spammy facebook applications.

Change your hosting provider ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for liking I have seen in Wordpress plugins.  Liking your Facebook page from the blog (very useful in my opinion) or liking the post.

These are the best two plugins for this:

Like your Facebook fan page: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-simple-like/

Like the specific post on your blog: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/share-this/

I would recommend a plugin.